# Probability of drawing x unique marbles from a bag of size y

Tags: probability

I'm sure a question like this has been asked before, but I couldn't find anything the way I was phrasing it.

Here's the scenario: I have a bag of $y$ marbles. There are $x$ different kinds of marbles. There is the same amount of each type (so $y$ is necessarily a multiple of $x$). Assume that there are at least z marbles of each type. So $y ≥ zx$.

Now, say I draw $z$ marbles from the bag, where $z ≥ x$. What is the probability that I draw every kind of marble?

Or, as a more general question, for any $z$, what is the probability I draw $w$ kinds of marbles, where $w ≤ z$?

I've been puzzling over this for a while, and I can't figure out how to start.

Comment: The answer to your question depends on whether there are at least $z$ marbles of each type.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Ah, you're right. I'm interested in large y-values, so I'll assume there are.

Comment: You may find some answers if you search for "coupon collector's problem".

Comment: @GerryMyerson This helps, though in my problem, there was no replacement. However, since I'm interested in large y-values, this should be close enough for my purposes.